Cannot handover parameters to tasker android via curl
I have the following terminal request on my Mac:
curl -X GET http://192.168.1.10:8080/callnumber?Number=+1234567890
The request is properly passed to my Tasker interface on Android.
However it seems that the Number or any parameter is never passed.
Parameters just show %Number or %Par1 or whatever I enter into the Text field of the Action as text. This happens as well when omitting callnumber alltogether to simplify the url.
Is there something I have missed?
Greetings, Meeee
